# .htaccess redirect when file does not exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I'm using .htaccess to redirect old site pages to new site pages. A typical rule in my file looks like this:

Redirect 301 /faqs.php http://blueprintprep.com/classroom/faq

Strangely, it works fine when the old file exists on the server, but when I remove the file, the final URL actually looks like this:

http://blueprintprep.com/classroom/faq?/faqs.php

What in the blue blazes is going on??

The file is made up of a bunch of these rules and this for CodeIgniter:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^application_consulting/(.*) http://blueprintprep.com/oneonone/app_consulting [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^weekend/(.*) http://blueprintprep.com/classroom [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^workshop/(.*) http://blueprintprep.com/oneonone [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What else is in the htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mod_rewrite` instead.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/faqs.php$ /classroom/faq [L,R=301]
```

This will work regardless if the file exists or not.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, this works great:) I'm still curious why the strange result when the file does not exist?

Comment: It looks like it's a result of your first `RewriteRule`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`.   I'm not sure where the `index.php` goes though, but that is my first thought.

Comment: Actually, I just saw that its a rewrite, not a redirect, so it shouldn't be effecting the actual URL...